# How to use a smart TV as a monitor via built-in Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a TV with built-in Wi-Fi adapter (Samsung Smart TV series 6). How can I use it a regular monitor using Wi-Fi instead of HDMI?

Currently I can use allShare software to cast videos to it.
I am looking for a software solution.

Comment: Depending on what you are displaying WiFi might be very laggy.  The technology is not 100% there for completely wireless HD viewing

Comment: Some ideas mentioned here might be worth a try: http://realmike.org/blog/2015/05/27/wip-mirror-your-linux-desktop-to-your-tv/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After two years, I have just succeeded to do that in Windows 10. Assuming you have all required hardware:

1. First be sure the TV source is switched to Screen Mirroring (each manufacturer may use a particular term for that.)
2. Also make sure the TV is listed among other devices in Devices and Printers windows.
3. Press windows+k keys and select your TV from list.
4. Now your monitors will act as a regular secondary HDMI monitor.
5. You may need to repeat this steps to succeed.

:)

Comment: It’s not really about Windows 10. There are three requirements: Windows 8.1 or higher, NDIS 6.3 WiFi, WDDM 1.3 Graphics.

Comment: @DanielB I had all of that but they were not working.

Answer (score 4):

Your laptop or mobile device should support Intel's WiDi (Wireless Display) and have a WiDi receiver, or you can purchase a WiDi adapter separately.  [It will be something like this
(NETGEAR Push2TV HD-TV Adapter for Intel Wireless Display PTV2000-100NAS HDMI Interface)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122453) but I am not recommending any particular such device.

Since I see that [Samsung made a deal in June 2013 to start including WiDi in their TVs](http://www.digitaltrends.com/home-theater/samsung-to-add-streaming-from-pcs-to-tvs/), it's unlikely that your current Samsung TV has this capability.

[Intel's information on WiDi is here](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-wireless-display.html), and you can look up adapters from that page or from on-line electronics companies; there are several manufacturers.

The type of Wi-fi built into your TV is for networking, i.e. access to media from other devices.  That is not the same as sending display content to use it as a monitor.  It's like asking how to open a can by using an egg-beater - the Wifi you have, despite having the word "wireless" in it, is not the same as WiDi which is used for displays.

I hope that some salesperson didn't tell you that this would work, because without WiDi, all you can do is display media on the TV from other connected devices, but not use it as a second monitor.

[Your question is similar to the one posted here](https://communities.intel.com/thread/36945).

This will also depend on the computer having WiDi capability; you haven't specified that, and only some have it (my Sony VAIO laptop has it included, but is advertised as such).

Comment: Because it's different to read media from a device, than to get its display output, I don't see how a software option will allow you to use this as a monitor without a connection (cabled or wi-di).  I'm not sure how to explain in a comment, but in one case, the TV is getting a signal that's essentially a series of pixels; in the other, it's reading files from the device (laptop etc.) These are completely different areas of functionality.  So if you really want to do this, I think your only current option is to get a WiDi adapter.

Comment: WiDi has been discontinued by Intel. It has been replaced by Miracast which is a very similar technology. Unfortunately, its support has been very buggy in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find an old laptop with wifi.
2. Connect the TV to it as a monitor.
3. Use remote desktop program on the old laptop to view and control
   your remote computer.

Comment: Do you have practical experiences with this? In my experiences X forwarding, VNC and stuff like this is not suitable for this purpose.

Comment: @WakanTanka They will offer performance similar to WiDi, so it’s really not much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "Samsung Screen Mirroring".

On Samsung TV: "Source - Screen Mirroring"

In Windows 8: right swipe - "devices - project" - you'll see your tv there

Not sure there's a solution for a Mac.

Comment: Thanks, it did not work. The I select projection mode the panel disappears without asking about the device.

Answer (score 0):

Devices - project works fine. You might have to switch the TV in Screen mirroring mode prior to project. Also, you'll probably need to remove and add the TV device

BTW, Windows 10 names it "Connect to the wireless display"